# react hooks, cant updating state via props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

trying to update state variable('visible') via internal function(setVisible) in component. I checked the [tutorıal](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and did same but its not updating after initialization of state.
Sandobx link [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-haze-wb2vw?fontsize=14).

props.visible is true when user click ShowModal button. but value of visible in function component is still false. (I have checked the content on debugger)

code:

```
import Modal from '../Helpers/AppModal'

    class Streams extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = { showModal: false }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getStreams()
        }

        showDeleteModal = (isShow) =>
        {
            this.setState({ showModal: isShow });
        }
        onClickBackdrop = () => {this.setState({ showModal: false });}

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={()=> this.showDeleteModal(true)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

                    <Modal visible={this.state.showModal} onClickBackdrop={this.onClickBackdrop} />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

AppModal.js:

```
 const AppModal = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(props.visible)
  useEffect(() =>{
    setVisible(props.visible)
},[props.visible])

  debugger
  return (
    <Modal visible={visible} fade={true} onClickBackdrop={props.onClickBackdrop}>
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title">{props.title}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              {props.body}
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
            <React.Fragment>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={()=>setVisible(false)}>
                Close
              </button>
            </React.Fragment>

            </div>
          </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think you should try like this: `setVisible(false)`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh did bvut still have issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument passed to `useState`is just the initial state. Pass a `prop` to it doesn't mean that the `state` will be synchronized with `props`. You can setup an effect to mirror those changes into your local state.

Currently your `Modal` only see `visible` from the local state, changing the `props` value won't cause `Modal` to change

```
//Inside child
useEffect(() =>{
    setVisible(props.visible)
},[props])
```

> Why should I use `props` instead of `props.visible` there?

The dependencies array exists to keep synchronicity, you're telling `react`:

"Hey, everytime one of those values changes re run this effect."

The problem is that `React` performs a shallow comparison (`Object.is`) between old and new `props`, uppon each `render` a new `props` object is generated which is what is triggering your effect in the first place.

React doesn't know how to "react" to nested changes. What is really changing here is `props`, react doesn't know (and doesn't care) about `props.visible`, passing it as a dependency is the same as passing `[]`

Actually passing `props` as dependency is useless, since `props` changes every render you can omit the dependencies array, which will trigger the effect on each render

```
useEffect(() => {
    setVisible(props.visible)
})
```

Comment: when I did this, it works fine for first click but not shows the modal after close and reclick the button

Comment: Can you post an example in a sandbox? You don't actually need `useState` here, but I'm assuming that your want to use it right?

Comment: Yes, I have created sandbox, hope it helps; https://codesandbox.io/embed/interesting-haze-wb2vw?fontsize=14

Comment: That was my mistake. I've passed `props.visible` as dependency, but you should pass `props`. updated the answer

Comment: btw can you tell me why it works, why would I use props instead of probs.visible there?

Answer (score 0):

`visible` is a boolean.

Try changing the way you call `setVisible` like so:

```
setVisible(false)
```

instead of

```
setVisible({visible:false})
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a toggle switch then you should do this:

```
onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}
```

Then it'll toggle on/off correctly.

You might want to set the initial value more explicitly though:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
```

Comment: done, but issue still here, I edited post(AppModal.js)

Comment: FYI by setting it to false on the onClick it will only ever work once. This is why I suggested setting it to false initially and then using the !visible flag in the onClick().

Comment: @TyForHelpDude In your code you refer to <Modal> but appmodal.js has it listed as AppModal - maybe alter the code to refer to it correctly?

Comment: its just an alias